# I'm having a problem with my code with python variables

Tags: python

```
temp = [i for i in range(1,len(arr)+1)]
for i in range(len(temp)):
    temp = shift_right(temp,len(temp)-i-1,arr[i])
print(temp)
solve(arr,temp)
print(temp)
```

this is in main. arr is another function telling how much to shift right/left

```
def solve(arrs,temps):
  for i in range(len(temps)):
    temps = shift_left(temps,i,arrs[i])
  return temps == [i for i in range(1,len(temps)+1)]

def shift_left(arrs, i , no_of_times):
  mid = arrs.pop(i)
  return arrs[:i-no_of_times:]+[mid]+arrs[i-no_of_times::]`

def shift_right(arrs, i , no_of_times):
  mid = arrs.pop(i)
  return arrs[:i+no_of_times:]+[mid]+arrs[i+no_of_times::]
```

these are my function definitions. Now here is the problem. i have not used global variable names or even used "global" keyword.
then why does my output look like this?

```
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1]
```

why did temp remove first element for no reason?

Comment: `arrs.pop()` is a _mutative_ operation - it affects the object to which the name 'arrs' refers, which is the _same object_ that the caller passed in (in `solve()`, this object is `temps`). Python passes by reference - calling a function simply creates a new name to refer to the same variable. You can reassign that name to point to something different with `=`, but if you call a mutative method like `.pop()`, it'll still modify the original object.

Comment: In this case, if you add the line `arrs = arrs.copy()` at the beginning of both `shift_left()` and `shift_right()`, it should hotfix your problem (creating a soft copy of the list that's passed in, and reassigning the name `arrs` to reference the copy and not the original, so that calling `.pop()` only modifies the copy)

Comment: you guys are legends. thanks for explaining. i used arrs.copy() and it works as a charm. also is there a way to not mutate object / create new object on function call, like how primary data types work?

Answer (score 0):

When passing the list, it is being send by reference not by value, so when it does the pop on shift_left it affects the original one, my solution around this is making a copy, something like this:

```py
def shift_left(arrs, i , no_of_times):
    newArrs=arrs[:]
    mid = newArrs.pop(i)
    # print(temp)
    return arrs[:i-no_of_times:]+[mid]+arrs[i-no_of_times::]
```

in short, python is passing the list by reference not by value by default